# Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What characters/symbols are allowed within the **CSS** class selectors?

I know that the following characters are *invalid*, but what characters are *valid*?

```
~ ! @ $ % ^ & * ( ) + = , . / ' ; : " ? > < [ ] \ { } | ` #
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812072/allowed-characters-for-css-identifiers

Comment: what about utf8 characters? Like i may type in greek

Comment: Special characters can be used in class names by escaping them - in your CSS file you can define a `.hello/world` class by escaping the backslash: `.hello\2fworld`, `hello\2f world` or `hello\/world`

Comment: Another related question, not about "syntax of names", but about "syntax of class attribute" when [expressing multiple names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13808846/287948).

Comment: @DarrylHein: The incorrect assumption is that CSS class selectors may not contain `-` or `_`.

Comment: You can also use emoji. https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-modules-emoji-classname

Comment: One of my favorite characters to use when naming classes is ⦘ . Look at how easy it is to read and understand  .BOX⦘BUTTON or .CARD⦘HERO .  Use multiple levels of identification .CARD⦘PAGE1⦘HERO and so on.  I think that labeling the class names in all caps makes everything way more readable .  You're welcome.

Comment: Other good unicode characters are as follows ⦁⦂⦚⦘┃◼░▯◊

Comment: @wyqydsyq I'm guessing that you meant "escaping WITH A backslash"?  In all of your examples, the backslash (`\`) was not escaped, but came before another character that it was apparently escaping.

Comment: Check these references :[https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors), [https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/](https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/)

Comment: What about TailWindCSS? It uses `:` in its classes and it seems to be valid

Answer (score 1121, accepted):

You can check directly at the [CSS grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner).

*Basically*<sup>1</sup>, a name must begin with an underscore (`_`), a hyphen (`-`), or a letter(`a`–`z`), followed by any number of hyphens, underscores, letters, or numbers. There is a catch: if the first character is a hyphen, the second character must<sup>2</sup> be a  letter or underscore, and the name must be at least 2 characters long.

```
-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*
```

In short, the previous rule translates to the following, extracted from the [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
> selectors) can contain only the characters [a-z0-9] and ISO 10646
> characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
> (_); they cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen followed by a digit.
> Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646
> character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the
> identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B&W?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Identifiers beginning with a hyphen or underscore are typically reserved for browser-specific extensions, as in `-moz-opacity`.

<sup>1</sup> It's all made a bit more complicated by the inclusion of escaped Unicode characters (that no one really uses).

<sup>2</sup> Note that, according to the grammar I linked, a rule starting with *two* hyphens, e.g., `--indent1`, is invalid.  However, I'm pretty sure I've seen this in practice.

Comment: NB: The W3C says that the use of a leading '-' or '_' should be reserved for vendor-specific CSS extensions (e.g., -moz* classes implemented by Mozilla browsers).

Comment: i added sample of not starting with _ - or letter but emoji. I do NOT recommend such naming for classes yet it works. Good to know for general curiosity. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69963534/1737158

Comment: [As of 2022, the CSS spec defines a class-name](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#w3cselgrammar) (in a `.css` rule's selector) as `"." + ident`, and the lexical scanner rules for `ident` specifially allow _any character_ outside of `0x00-0x7F` in a class name after an initial `[_A-Za-z]` character, so the `[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*` pattern posted here is incorrect.

Answer (score 218):

To my surprise most answers here are wrong. It turns out that:

**Any character except NUL is allowed in CSS class names in CSS.** (If CSS contains NUL (escaped or not), the result is undefined. [[CSS-characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)]) *In HTML* though, permanently unassigned codepoints are not permitted either. Neither does HTML have a way to include [space characters (space, tab, line feed, form feed and carriage return)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html#space-character) in a [class name attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#classes), because those are class *lists* and spaces are used here to separate class names from each other.

[Mathias Bynens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6592488/8554766) links to [explanation](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) and [demos](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/crazy-class) showing how to use these names. *Written down* in CSS code, a class name *may need escaping*, but that doesn’t change the class name. E.g. an unnecessarily over-escaped representation will look different from other representations of that name, but it still refers to the same class name.

Most other (programming) languages don’t have that concept of escaping variable names (“identifiers”), so all representations of a variable have to look the same. This is not the case in CSS.

So, if you need to turn a random string into a CSS class name: take care of NUL and space, and escape (accordingly for CSS or HTML). Done.

Answer (score 88):

I’ve answered your question in-depth at *[CSS character escape sequences](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)*. The article also explains how to escape any character in CSS (and JavaScript), and I made [a handy tool](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0%7E!%40%24%25%5E%26%2A%28%29%5F%2B-%3D%2C.%2F%27%3B%3A%22%3F%3E%3C%5B%5D%5C%7B%7D%7C%60%23) for this as well. From that page:

> If you were to give an element an ID value of `` ~!@$%^&*()_+-=,./';:"?><[]{}|`# ``, the selector would look like this:
>
> **CSS:**
>
> ```css
> <style>
>   #\~\!\@\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+-\=\,\.\/\'\;\:\"\?\>\<\[\]\\\{\}\|\`\#
>   {
>     background: hotpink;
>   }
> </style>
> ```
>
> **JavaScript:**
>
> ```js
> <script>
>   // document.getElementById or similar
>   document.getElementById('~!@$%^&*()_+-=,./\';:"?><[]\\{}|`#');
>   // document.querySelector or similar
>   $('#\\~\\!\\@\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\_\\+-\\=\\,\\.\\/\\\'\\;\\:\\"\\?\\>\\<\\[\\]\\\\\\{\\}\\|\\`\\#');
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 72):

Read the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters). (this is CSS 2.1; find the appropriate version for your assumption of browsers)

relevant paragraph:

> In CSS, identifiers  (including
> element names, classes, and IDs in
> selectors) can contain only the
> characters [a-z0-9] and ISO 10646
> characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the
> hyphen (-) and the underscore (_);
> they cannot start with a digit, or a
> hyphen followed by a digit.
> Identifiers can also contain escaped
> characters and any ISO 10646 character
> as a numeric code (see next item). For
> instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be
> written as "B&W?" or "B\26 W\3F".

As [@mipadi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors#comment269931_449000) points out in [Kenan Banks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors/449000#449000), there's this [caveat](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords), also in the same webpage:

> In CSS, identifiers may begin with '-'
> (dash) or '_' (underscore). Keywords
> and property names beginning with '-'
> or '_' are reserved for
> vendor-specific extensions. Such
> vendor-specific extensions should have
> one of the following formats:
>
> ```
> '-' + vendor identifier + '-' + meaningful name
> '_' + vendor identifier + '-' + meaningful name
> ```
>
> Example(s):
>
> For example, if XYZ organization added
> a property to describe the color of
> the border on the East side of the
> display, they might call it
> -xyz-border-east-color.
>
> Other known examples:
>
> ```
> -moz-box-sizing
> -moz-border-radius
> -wap-accesskey
> ```
>
> An initial dash or underscore is
> guaranteed never to be used in a
> property or keyword by any current or
> future level of CSS. Thus typical CSS
> implementations may not recognize such
> properties and may ignore them
> according to the rules for handling
> parsing errors. However, because the
> initial dash or underscore is part of
> the grammar, CSS 2.1 implementers
> should always be able to use a
> CSS-conforming parser, whether or not
> they support any vendor-specific
> extensions.
>
> Authors should avoid vendor-specific
> extensions

Answer (score 28):

The complete regular expression is:

```
-?(?:[_a-z]|[\200-\377]|\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\[^\r\n\f0-9a-f])(?:[_a-z0-9-]|[\200-\377]|\\[0-9a-f]{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\[^\r\n\f0-9a-f])*
```

So all of your listed characters, except “`-`” and “`_`” are not allowed if used directly. But you can encode them using a backslash `foo\~bar` or using the Unicode notation `foo\7E bar`.

Answer (score 18):

For those looking for a workaround, you can use an attribute selector, for instance, if your class begins with a number. Change:

```
.000000-8{background:url(../../images/common/000000-0.8.png);} /* DOESN'T WORK!! */
```

to this:

```
[class="000000-8"]{background:url(../../images/common/000000-0.8.png);} /* WORKS :) */
```

Also, if there are multiple classes, you will need to specify them in selector or use the `~=` operator:

```css
[class~="000000-8"]{background:url(../../images/common/000000-0.8.png);}
```

**Sources:**

1. https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/
2. [Is there a workaround to make CSS classes with names that start with numbers valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227702/is-there-a-workaround-to-make-css-classes-with-names-that-start-with-numbers-val)
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 9):

I **would not recommend to use anything except A-z, _- and 0-9**, while it's just easier to code with those symbols. Also do not start classes with `-` while those classes are usually browser-specific flags. To avoid any issues with IDE autocompletion, less complexity when you may need to generate those class names with some other code for whatever reason. Maybe some [transpiling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transpile#Verb) software may not work, etc., etc.

Yet CSS is quite loose on this. You can use any symbol, and even [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) works.

```
<style>
  . {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>

<div class="">
  
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that the underscore is technically valid. Check out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/underscores_in_class_and_id_names

"...errata to the specification published in early 2001 made underscores legal for the first time."

The article linked above says never use them, then gives a list of browsers that don't support them, all of which are, in terms of numbers of users at least, long-redundant.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Page not found"*

Answer (score 6):

We can use all characters in a class name. Even characters like `#` and `.`. We  just have to escape them with `\` (backslash).

```css
.test\.123 {
  color: red;
}

.test\#123 {
  color: blue;
}

.test\@123 {
  color: green;
}

.test\<123 {
  color: brown;
}

.test\`123 {
  color: purple;
}

.test\~123 {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="test.123">test.123</div>
<div class="test#123">test#123</div>
<div class="test@123">test@123</div>
<div class="test<123">test<123</div>
<div class="test`123">test`123</div>
<div class="test~123">test~123</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

For HTML5 and CSS 3, [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_attribute#Common_attributes) and [IDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_attribute#Common_attributes) can start with numbers.

Comment: But css selectors still need to be escaped by unicode code point. Ex: css selector for class `10` needs to be `.\31 0`

Answer (score 0):

Going off of [Kenan Banks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors/449000#449000), you can use the following two regex matches to make a string valid:

```
[^a-z0-9A-Z_-]
```

This is a reverse match that selects anything that isn't a letter, number, dash or underscore for easy removal.

```
^-*[0-9]+
```

This matches 0 or 1 dashes followed by 1 or more numbers at the beginning of a string, also for easy removal.

How I use it in PHP:

```php
// Make alphanumeric with dashes and underscores (removes all other characters)
$class = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9A-Z_-]/", "", $class);

// Classes only begin with an underscore or letter
$class = preg_replace("/^-*[0-9]+/", "", $class);

// Make sure the string is two or more characters long
return 2 <= strlen($class) ? $class : '';
```